# Scheduled terminal command or script file to run daily at a specific time Mac OS X Gets Property Error

Tags: macos

I have this file saved in the ~/Library/LaunchAgents folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>     <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList- 1.0.dtd">     <plist version="1.0">       <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.videohub.getepg</string> 
    <key>UserName</key>         <string>videohub</string>         <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/videohub/Scripts/getepg</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict> 
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>3</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

When I go to run it, I get the message 'Invalid Property List'.  I can't see what's wrong with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you have Unicode "Line Separator" ([U+2028](https://codepoints.net/U+2028)) characters instead of plain newlines in some places. This is not allowed in property list files.

Comment: Thanks.  How did you see that?  It looks like regular carriage returns to me.  I take them out and see how it goes.

Comment: First, the file looked weird in the question, apparently because of how stackoverflow formats code sections. Then I copy-pasted it into a file (fortunately that preserved the unicode characters!), and ran `plutil -lint filename.plist` (a general plist sanity-checker), and it said "Unexpected character â at line 1". So I looked at the file in more detail with `xxd file.plist`, spotted the weird multibyte characters (e.g. "`462d 3822 3f3e e280 a820 2020 203c 2144  F-8"?>...    <!D`" -- the bit that shows as `e2 80 a8` in hex and "`...`" as text, googled "utf-8 e280a8" and had an answer.